# Tooltip for ITableLabelProvider

Tags: swt, jface, viewer

I have a problem regarding the tooltips in my Table.

It seems the only way to get tooltips is to use a ColumnLabelProvider.
But all my tables work with the ITableLabelProvider and would need a lot of refactoring and work.

Is there any workaround to provide my tables with tooltips?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything, `ITableLabelProvider` is an older interface that was added before the tool tip support.

When you use `ITableLabelProvider` JFace is actually using an internal `ColumnLabelProvider` (called `TableColumnViewerLabelProvider`) but there is no way to get that to do tool tips.

I don't think you can adapt `ColumnViewerToolTipSupport` since it relies on a number of package private methods in the viewer.